# Oracle Forms 10g auto query

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

I'm creating a form which is populated by a data block query.

Let's say that I had an EMPLOYEE table, with the columns "ID" and "NAME".

Select ID, NAME from EMPLOYEE;

How can I trigger this automatically when the form loads (and is there a property or trigger designed to do this?)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no automatic way of doing this so you need to navigate to the database block (if this block is not the First Navigation Data Block of the form) and then execute the query form forms builtin Execute_Query. This can e.g. be done in form level trigger When-New-Form-Instance:

```
Go_Block(<name of your database block>);

Execute_Query;
```

Comment: Thanks DJPeter! It lets me execute the query when the window pops up. That was what I was looking for.

Comment: You can also use plsql to do a
`declare
begin

    go_block('Report');
    do_key ('execute_query');
    go_block('RPT2);
    do_key ('execute_query');
end;`